# Bug Logging Mechanism using TFS and Git

Tags: git, tfs

We are using GIT as Version control system and TFS for tracking PBI and Bugs for our new product development in Microsoft Technologies.

Developers create a feature branch as and when they pick up a new task or a PBI. When completed development, they release it for testing and QA team perform testing on the feature branch.

I wanted to ask here how these feature branch bugs should be logged in TFS so that they are separated from the bugs which are been raised on the production environment or the staging environment. TFS consider each as a bug be it a feature branch or production environment bug, but Business is more interested in looking at production or staging environment bugs and least interested in Feature bugs as this is between developer and tester.

But as a Scrum master, it is important to track feature branch related bugs as well.

So can someone suggest how to track feature bugs and production bugs separately using TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to do it.  I see 2 possibilities :

1. You create an area that will contain all your feature branch bugs
2. You use a tag on these feature branch bug and create queries to filter on that tag.

And a third highly not recommended :

3. You create a new workitem template for these bugs (copy paste from the bug template)